# Cap Wearing Problem

Tags: logic

Five men $A,B,C,D$ and $E$ are wearing caps of either black or white colour without knowing the colour of their own caps but they can see others caps. It is known that a man wearing black cap always speaks the truth and a man wearing white cap always speaks lies. They made the following statements

$A$: I see $3$ black caps and $1$ white cap

$B$: I see $4$ white caps

$C$: I see $3$ white caps and $1$ black cap

$D$: I see $4$ black caps

$E$: "no statement made"

Find the colour of caps worn by each of them

I tried to solve it by using some tricks. I just guessed it as white ,white,black,white and black

Is there any more formal way to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I don't know about formal but I'd start with Bs statement which is equivalent to "everybody but me is lying".  If it is true B has a black cap and C's statement would be true.  But B just said C was lying.  So B's statement is not true.  So we *know* B has a white cap. and is lying.  ANdy I'd go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $B$.

If $B$ is telling the truth then $B$ has a black cap and everyone else is white.

The $C$s statement if true.  But that would mean $C$ has a black cap which contradicts that everyone but $B$ is white.

So $B$ was lying and $B$ has a white cap.

But $D$ says he only sees black caps so he is lying and $D$ has a white cap.

But $A$ say he only sees one white cap so he is lying and $A$ has a white cap.

Now either $C$ is telling the truth or lying.

If $C$ is telling the truth, then $E$ have black caps. And so does $C$ That is consistent.

If $C$ is lying then, $E$ has a white cap and $C$ has a white cap.  So everyone has a white cap.  But that means $B$ was telling the truth which we already determined is impossible.

So the only consistent possibility is $C$ and $D$ have black caps and tell the truth.

....

BY THE WAY you say the men don't know the colors of their own hats.  And yet white caps lie and black caps tell truth... SO that means the men don't know if they are telling the truth or if they are lying?

Best to leave out that condition they don't know their own color.  It's not part of the puzzle anyway. And the idea that a hat can magically turn a man into a liar or a truth-teller *without* the man knowing and the man can't *know* if he's lying or telling the truth is just too weird.

Comment: Such weird questions come only in jmo odisha

Comment: I attempted that exam this sunday

Comment: It's a fine puzzle.  But as the *men* aren't trying to figure out their own color, it's an unnecessary (and unfathomable) condition.  After all If I wanted to figure out what color hat I had on I'd just say aloud "One plus one equals...." and if I said $2$ I'd know I had a black cap if I said "a green cat" I'd know I had a white cap.  Then I'd spend the rest of the day pondering the nature of free will....

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Suppose B's statement is true.  Then everyone is wearing a white cap, so D's statement is false, and D must be wearing a black cap.  This contradiction means that B's statement must be false, so B is wearing a black cap.

Try to continue in this way.

Comment: I just need the answer for checking